# Amazon Fire tablet not accessible using ubuntu 20.04 issue

Tags: usb, tablet, usb-drive

I have an amazon fire tablet 7 and can't access it using the file managers.

I can see it in the terminal with

**lsusb**

```
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 1949:0338 Lab126, Inc. KFKAWI
```

**lsusb -v**

```
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 1949:0338 Lab126, Inc. KFKAWI
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1949 Lab126, Inc.
  idProduct          0x0338 
  bcdDevice            2.23
  iManufacturer           1 Amazon
  iProduct                2 KFKAWI
  iSerial                 3 G0W0T9058472F2WF
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0020
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 adb
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass     66 
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 
      iInterface              5 ADB Interface
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

I'm using

```
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal


Linux sys76 5.4.0-84-generic #94-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 26 20:27:37 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you install any mtp packages/tools? Those are probably necessary. Some devices might need to explicitly select MTP over PTP from the device's USB connection notification

Comment: The fix is probably not on the Ubuntu side. There usually is a setting in the Developer Opions of Android devices to allow MTP access. Not sure if it is exposed to the user on Amazon tablets.

Comment: @ubfan1 yes mtp is installed

Comment: @mikewhatever it works on another ubuntu 20.04 computer just not this particular laptop.

Comment: So, what is different about the two?

Comment: @mikewhatever I don't know they both use the same version of ubuntu 20.04.3.  Is there something I could do to find that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue with inability to connect to Amazon Fire device.
This worked for me:

1. Avoid connecting device through a USB hub; connect directly to one of the USB ports on your *buntu system
2. Download and install:
   android-file-transfer
   gmtp
   go-mtpfs
   mtp-tools
3. Open your file manager - file structure of your device should be visible.

My System: Xubuntu 22.04.1